# intersection query: who are in the same team of mine?

Tags: mongodb

Say: User doc is like {_id, name, teamIds:[...]}.

I joined many teams, and others may joined many other teams.

How can I find out all users who are in any one of my teams?

Or, if it is not a efficient design, add a collection with {teamId, userId} is the best bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straightforward if your user is fetched already (which it likely is).

```
db.users.find({_id: {$ne: me.id}, teams: {$in: me.teams}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following documents in your users collections,

```
 { 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "teams" : [
        1.0, 
        5.0, 
        8.0, 
        12.0, 
        10.0
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2.0, 
    "teams" : [
        1.0, 
        2.0, 
        3.0, 
        8.0, 
        10.0
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 3.0, 
    "teams" : [
        4.0, 
        7.0, 
        9.0, 
        12.0
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 5.0, 
    "teams" : [
        21.0, 
        45.0, 
        85.0
    ]
}
```

and you want to get all users that share any team with user id 1. You can achieve this by using  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-uncorrelated-subuery)  stage :

```
db['users'].aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
        _id:1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            let: { id:"$_id", team:"$teams" },
            pipeline: [ {$match:{$expr:{$and:[
              {$ne:["$_id","$$id"]},
              {$ne:[{$setIntersection:["$teams","$$team"]},[]]}
              ]}}}],
            as: "connected_users"
         }
    },
],
);
```

This will output :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1.0, 
    "teams" : [
        1.0, 
        5.0, 
        8.0, 
        12.0, 
        10.0
    ], 
    "connected_users" : [
        {
            "_id" : 2.0, 
            "teams" : [
                1.0, 
                2.0, 
                3.0, 
                8.0, 
                10.0
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0, 
            "teams" : [
                4.0, 
                7.0, 
                9.0, 
                12.0
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: really sure? Did you try? If you do this, you will get users who share all teams with 'me'.  `db.users.find({teams: {$in:me.teams}})` can achieve it, but still return 'me' as connected user,

Comment: yeah, excluding self is trivial, I have added that to my comment before upgrading it to an answer. (and yeah, I am spoiled by mongoid, ruby library, which adds that `$in` for me. Thought it's the same in the shell)